# Manipulating the hash/anchor part of the URL in Actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, url, actionscript-2

How can you get and set the hash or anchor part of an URL in pure Actionscript? When googling for a solution I've found explainations for doing it using JavaScript, but is it possible to get it without using JavaScript? (I'm using Actionscript 2, I may consider updating the code to AS 3, but it doesn't seem to be a quite straight forward process.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is [SWFAdress](http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/), it's a small library that let's you modify that part of the url from flash (via a javascript)

Comment: It's probably useful, but it is based on JavaScript. I wanted to know if it is possible at all to do this without JavaScript, but I'm starting to beleave it's not.

Comment: You will always need javascript.

Answer (score -1):

If you ever make it to actionscript3 you could use the [com.adobe.net.URI class](http://weblogs.macromedia.com/as_libraries/docs/corelib/com/adobe/net/URI.html). It exposes a URI::fragment getter/setter which looks to be exactly what you need.

Comment: SWFAddress is the tool for the job. Anything else is simply .. unnecessary. SWFAddress is available for AS2 or AS3 so you never have to write your own.